# Determine the value of $\angle BAC+2\angle BCA$ in degrees

Tags: geometry, angle

> Given triangle $ABC$ with high point $H$. If $\angle ABC=80^\circ$ and $\angle AHB-\angle BHC=40^\circ$, then determine the value of $\angle BAC+2\angle BCA$ in degrees.

I'm not sure about the process, what I think is that the high point $H$ must divide perpendicularly so that the $\angle AHB$ and $\angle BHC$ are $90^\circ$, but in the $\angle AHB-\angle BHC= 40^\circ$. Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Could you please draw a diagram?

Comment: @MeltedStatementRecognizing I'm a new account user here, so I don't know how to add a draw digram

Comment: what is a high point

Comment: Draw a diagram, then take a screenshot and copy and paste into your question.

Comment: @MeltedStatementRecognizing https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjgAv.png is the draw a diagram like that?

Comment: Yes thank you! .

Comment: @JustinAlexander, okay, so $<AHB - <BHC = 40$, and they are supplementary so $<ABH + <BHC = 180$. Using algebra, can you figure it out from there?

Comment: @MeltedStatementRecognizing I'm confused how to draw it, the shape is weird

Comment: Is it a pyramid and the high point is the apex?

Comment: Is this the original wording of the problem? If so, please clarify the 'high point'.